# What can I do to search for a string in a really big txt file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, file, search

I have met with a problem which I can't find a good way to solve it.

Problem description:

```
File 1: short_map.txt, contains with over 2millon lines with each line consist of a short url like the one in twitter and its corresponding full web url.
```

(eg."http://bit.ly/18sy7Fzhttp://www.london24.com/spurs_star_townsend_deemed_hodgson_joke_a_compliment_1_2903643?utm_source=Daily+News&utm_medium=twitter"
)

```
File 2: html_index.txt, contains with about 50k lines with each line stands for a full web url.
```

(eg."http://www.redbubble.com/people/tipptoggy/works/10898437-rock-of-cashel")

I want to get the corresponding short url of each web url in the html_index.txt file and output it into a new txt file.

My way of doing it is to read each line of html_index.txt and then compare it with each line in short_map.txt and with this way I can get everything I want. The problem is: it's too slow!

Could anyone help me with a way faster algorithm to do this?

**Problem solved: Using hash table will work, refer to the first answer please! Thanks!**

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Read the short_map.txt file contents into a hash where in the key would be the long url and the corresponding short url would be its value. When you want to retrieve a short url, you could just do a hash lookup, which is extremely fast.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it's working perfectly. Thanks!